# Default Price List is not set while creating product bundlle Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-365-sales

I am trying to set default price list for a product bundle that i am trying to create using `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies`. I have written the working code that successfully creates the product bundle with all the configurations that I specify in the code  but default price list is never set. Following is the code snippet:

```
  Entity ProductBundleEntity = new Entity("product");
                ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["name"] = Name;
                ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["productstructure"] = new OptionSetValue(3);
                ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["productnumber"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
///// setting defult price list here
                ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["pricelevelid"] = new EntityReference("pricelevel", PriceListID);
                ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["defaultuomscheduleid"] = new EntityReference("uomschedule", UOMScheduleID);
                ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["defaultuomid"] = new EntityReference("uom", UOMID);
```

Please suggest if i am missing anything.

Comment: did you receive any error? When is your plugin running, create/update?Is it synchronous?

Comment: no it runs without any error, i am trying to set it during `create`. And yes it is synchronous

Comment: is it pre operation or post?
If post you might have to use service.update(Entity object)
Better try with pre operation so that same object/ can be used.

Comment: I am not aware of 'pre' or 'post' concepts for these operations. But as the definition of (pre/post) suggest, this seems to be the pre operation where i am setting the attribute (pricelevelid) of product bundle entity then calling service.create(productbundleentity). I have not tried to set price list as an `update` operation. let me try that

Comment: setting price list using update operation worked.

Comment: I shall add my comment as answer, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you receive any error?
When is your plugin running, create/update?
Is it synchronous? –
is it pre operation or post?

If post you might have to use service.update(Entity object) Better try with pre operation so that same object/ can be used.

Comment: This hint actually worked. Default price list is set for the entity if we set it using `service.update(entity)` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the definition of the PriceListId variable, normally you need to assign an id as below, I think the PriceListId variable does not contain a value;

ProductBundleEntity.Attributes["pricelevelid"] = new EntityReference("pricelevel", ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference)(originalEntity.Attributes["pricelevelid"])).Id);

Comment: 'PriceListId' is basically the GUID of 'UK Price List' in Dynamics, and I've checked while debugging, it's not null/incorrect. Otherwise code would have thrown an error while creating entity reference.